# How to inject into nodejs stream

Tags: node.js, buffer, mp3, icecast

I have the following script it works however I can't figure out the best solution that when a metadata tag is triggered it is to stop/pause the stream play an mp3 URL and then reconnect to the stream (as a new connection).

My first idea worked, however, it seemed to pause the Icecast stream and then insert the mp3 and after that play, it just continued playing from the paused spot (that is not wanted). What I would like is if the mp3 is 2minutes long then the Icecast stream should also have been 2 minutes skipped.

```
var http = require('http'),request = require('request');
var url = 'http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8003/stream'; // URL to a known Icecast stream


var icecast = require('icecast-stack');
var stream = icecast.createReadStream(url);

// var radio = require("radio-stream");
// var stream = radio.createReadStream(url);

var clients = [];

stream.on("connect", function() {
  console.error("Radio Stream connected!");
  //console.error(stream.headers);
});

// Fired after the HTTP response headers have been received.
stream.on('response', function(res) {
  console.error("Radio Stream response!");
  console.error(res.headers);
});


// When a chunk of data is received on the stream, push it to all connected clients
stream.on("data", function (chunk) {
    if (clients.length > 0){
        for (client in clients){
            clients[client].write(chunk);
        };
    }
});

// When a 'metadata' event happens, usually a new song is starting.
stream.on('metadata', function(metadata) {
  var title = icecast.parseMetadata(metadata).StreamTitle;
  console.error(title);

});


// Listen on a web port and respond with a chunked response header. 
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){ 
    res.writeHead(200,{
        "Content-Type": "audio/mpeg",
        'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
    });
    // Add the response to the clients array to receive streaming
    clients.push(res);
    console.log('Client connected; streaming'); 
});
server.listen("9000", "127.0.0.1");

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:9000');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply arbitrarily concatenate streams like this.  With MP3, the bit reservoir will bite you.  Generally, it will be a small stream glitch, but you can have more picky clients just outright drop the connection.

To do what you want to do, you actually need to decode everything to PCM, mix the audio as you see fit, and then re-encode a fresh stream.

As an added bonus, you won't be tied to a particular codec and bitrate, and can offer an appropriate array of choices to your listeners.  You also won't have to worry about the timing of MPEG frames, as your final stream can be sample-accurate.